# Are parameterized lambda terms a Monad?

Tags: haskell, lambda, monads

I have this representation of terms in the lambda calculus parameterized over the type of the name:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Lambda a = Var a | App (Lambda a) (Lambda a) | Lam a (Lambda a) 
    deriving Functor
```

I was wondering if `Lambda` can be made an instance of monad? I thought that something like the following might work for the implementation of `join`:

```
joinT :: Lambda (Lambda a) -> Lambda a
joinT (Var a) = a
joinT (fun `App` arg) = joinT fun `App` joinT arg
joinT (Lam n body) = ?
```

For the third case I have absolutely no clue ... but it should be possible - 
this nameless representation of lambda-terms, taken from [De Bruijn Notation as a Nested Datatype](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/debruijn.ps.gz), is an instance of Monad (`Maybe` is used to discriminate between bound and free variables in this representation):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Expr a 
    = V a
    | A (Expr a) (Expr a)
    | L (Expr (Maybe a))
    deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

gfoldT :: forall m n b.
    (forall a. m a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n a -> n a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n (Maybe a) -> n a) ->
    (forall a. (Maybe (m a)) ->  m (Maybe a)) ->
    Expr (m b) -> n b
gfoldT v _ _ _ (V x) = v x
gfoldT v a l t (fun `A` arg) = a (gfoldT v a l t fun) (gfoldT v a l t arg)
gfoldT v a l t (L body) = l (gfoldT v a l t (fmap t body))

joinT :: Expr (Expr a) -> Expr a
joinT = gfoldT id (:@) Lam distT

distT :: Maybe (Expr a) -> Expr (Maybe a)
distT Nothing = Var Nothing
distT (Just x) = fmap Just x
```

`joinT` is sufficient for `instance Monad Expr`:

```
instance Applicative Expr where
    pure = Var
    ef <*> ea = do
        f <- ef
        a <- ea
        return $ f a

instance Monad Expr where
    return = Var
    t >>= f = (joinT . fmap f) t
```

Assume further the following two transformation functions between the representations:
`unname :: Lamba a -> Expr a` and `name :: Expr a -> Lambda a`. With those we can implement `join` for Lambda by exploiting the isomorphism between the two type constructors:

```
joinL :: Lambda (Lambda a) -> Lambda a
joinL = name . joinT . uname . fmap uname
```

But this seems very complicated. Is there a more straightforward way, or am I missing something important?

---

Edit: Here are the functions `name` and `uname` that I thought would do the job. As was pointed out in the comments and the answer, `a` really needs an `Eq` constraint which breaks the isomorphism.

```
foldT :: forall n b.
    (forall a. a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n a -> n a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n (Maybe a) -> n a) ->
    Expr b -> n b
foldT v _ _ (V x) = v x
foldT v a l (A fun arg) = a (foldT v a l fun) (foldT v a l arg)
foldT v a l (L body) = l (foldT v a l body)

abstract :: Eq a => a -> Expr a -> Expr a
abstract x = L . fmap (match x)

match :: Eq a => a -> a -> Maybe a
match x y = if x == y then Nothing else Just y

apply :: Expr a -> Expr (Maybe a) -> Expr a
apply t = joinT . fmap (subst t . fmap V)

uname :: Eq a => Lambda a -> Expr a
uname = foldL V A abstract

name :: Eq a => Expr a -> Lambda a
name e = nm [] e where
    nm vars (V n) = Var n
    nm vars (A fun arg) = nm vars fun `App` nm vars arg
    nm vars (L body) =
        Lam fresh $ nm (fresh:vars) (apply (V fresh) body) where
        fresh = head (names \\ vars)

names :: [String]
names = [ [i] | i <- ['a'..'z']] ++ [i : show j | j <- [1..], i <- ['a'..'z'] ]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but I can't see how `name`,`unname` would work. How do you turn e.g. `Lam (\x -> x+1) (Var (\y -> 2*y)) :: Lambda (Int->Int)` into a `Expr (Int->Int)`? Are these types really isomorphic? Wouldn't this conversion require `Eq` for functions? (just guessing here...)

Comment: @chi you're right ... `a` needs an `Eq` constrained. Does that break Isomorphism?

Comment: I mentioned that because constraints and `Monads` do not mix well. E.g. `Set` should be a monad, but the `Ord` constraints involved prevent that. Also, `Lam fresh ...` looks as a `Lambda String` value, not a `Lambda a`. Does that really type check?

Comment: @chi, as someone mentioned in another recent answer, `Set` is only a functor in a *non-full* subcategory of `Hask`. The only admitted morphisms are bijections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your instinct was right: terms which feature explicit names at binding sites do not form a monad.

The signature of `>>=` offers some food for thought:

```
(>>=) :: Lambda a -> (a -> Lambda b) -> Lambda b
```

Binding a lambda term performs *substitution*. The function you bind is the environment mapping names `a` to terms `Lambda b`; `>>=` finds all the occurences of names `a` and swaps each for the value from the environment to which it refers. (Compare `a -> Lambda b` with a more traditional environment type, `[(a, Lambda b)]`).

But it doesn't make sense to substitute at a binding site. The argument of a lambda term can't syntactically be a lambda. (`\(\x -> y) -> y` is not syntactically valid.) Putting an `a` in your `Lam` constructor means `Lambda` can't be a monad.

The particular law that you'd violate is *right identity*, which states `x >>= return = x` for all `x`. (To see the violation, try setting `x` to a `Lam` term.)

---

To see it another way, consider how you'd implement the capture-avoiding substitution that `>>=` provides in Paterson and Bird's paper. Capture-avoiding substitution is tricky when you're not using de Bruijn indices: you need a source of fresh names and the ability to identify coinciding names (to determine when you need to use a fresh one). The type of such a function would look something like:

```
subst :: (MonadFresh a m, Eq a) => Lambda a -> (a -> Lambda a) -> m (Lambda a)
```

The class constraints and the monadic context make this signature very different than that of `>>=`! If you actually tried to implement `name` and `unname` you would see that the types you hypothesised were incorrect, and that `joinL` would require these classes.

Bird and Paterson's representation of lambda terms is a monad because it is *locally nameless*. There's no `a` in their `L` constructor; instead, you find a variable's binding site by zooming out as far as the variable's value is long. As the paper explains, this is one way of representing de Bruijn indices (compare `Just (Just Nothing)` with the natural number `S (S Z)`).

For more, see Kmett's [detailed article](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/bound) describing the design of his [`bound`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-1.0.7) library, which uses Bird and Paterson's approach as one source of inspiration.